# php mongo aggregate - loop through an array php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am getting an array from mongo aggregate in PHP.

I am not able to read the array data in a loop. When I read the array it just gives me empty values.

I want data of `communityId` and `branchcity`. I am attaching my array and PHP code I am not able to find what am doing wrong.

My array is:

```
Array
(

[result] => Array (

[0] => Array (

        [libraryId] => LIB1002
        [communityId] => COM1
        [match_case] => Array (

        [0] => Array (

                [libraryId] => LIB1002
                [libraryName] => Oval Box
                [branchCity] => BRAN1002

                )
               )
        )
    [1] => Array (

        [libraryId] => LIB1003
        [match_case] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [libraryId] => LIB1003
                [libraryName] => House Keeping
                [branchCity] => BRAN1003
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

> [ok] => 1

PHP code

```
foreach ($library_selectdetails as $doc )

{

   echo $doc['libraryId'];

   echo $doc['match_case']['branchCity'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values, you have to use the key `results`. As `communityId` is missing from the second array, you could check for the key first.

```
foreach ($library_selectdetails["result"] as $doc) {
    if (array_key_exists("communityId", $doc)) {
        echo $doc["communityId"] . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $doc['match_case']['branchCity'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/SgOPl)